# Javascript global array .push returns last added element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, global-variables, push

I am trying to retrieve en array via alert but after every click I get the same value 1 instead of more 1 after each click. I tried both with loop and without. I tried `var seats = new Array();` too.

What I am doing wrong?

```
var seats = [];

function loadSubmitBtn() {
     document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", function () {
          showArray();
     });
 }

function showArray() {

   seats.push("1");

   var test = "";

   for (i = 0; i < seats .length; i++) {
       test += seats [i];
   }

   alert(test);
   alert(seats);
}
```

Comment: You're probably submitting a form and therefore refreshing the page. Use a `<input type="button">`

Comment: FYI, you can drop the anonymous function for the handler. Just pass `showArray` *(without the parens)*. `document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", showArray);`

Comment: Also FYI, you don't need a loop to create the string. Just do `alert(seats.join(""))`

Comment: @squint Yes, I have `<input type="submit">` and it works when I change it to `<input type="button">`

Answer (score 0):

I was using `<input type="submit">` and it is working after I changed it to `<input type="button">`